# Installing Freeradius-LDAP 3.x from PPA - Repository

Tags: ldap, openldap, radius, freeradius

Initially I've installed Freeradius from stable branch as follows:

```
apt-get install python-software-properties
apt-add-repository ppa:freeradius/stable-3.0
apt-get update
apt-get install freeradius make
```

And I thought, that all modules were also installed; but now, when I need to get Freeradius be authenticated against LDAP-Directory, and I'm  trying to reconfigure Freeradius and when I run it in Debugging mode (-X) I see the following error:

```
/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/ldap: Failed to link to module 'rlm_ldap' : /user/lib/freeradius/rlm_ldap.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

That's why I believe, that LDAP-Module for Freeradius was not be installed.

How could I make it from PPA:repository from the same branch, in order to not damage Freeradius and get them both (with LDAP-module) working.

Ubuntu Server 16.04.1TLS, Freeradius 3.11

Update1:

```
$dpkg -l | grep freeradius 

freeradius        3.0.11-ppa3~xenial
freeradius-common 3.0.11-ppa3~xenial
freeradius-config 3.0.11-ppa3~xenial
freeradius-utils  3.0.11-ppa3~xenial
libfreeradius3    3.0.11-ppa3~xenial
```

Comment: Please add to the question the output of `dpkg -l | grep freeradius`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have support for LDAP in FreeRadius, please install the corresponding package with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install freeradius-ldap
```

Also relating to your doubts about mixed versions, to check up the version installed, do:

```
dpkg -l | grep freeradius
```

and/or:

```
dpkg -l freeradius-ldap
```

Comment: From the source it must be version 2 installed, but v.3 is not compatible with v.2

Comment: @user3467471  Add it also to dpkg -l output. From what we see till now, all are version 3.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Sorry, what do you mean? I have v.3 of Freeradius installed and would also get the same version of Ldap-modul for it. Or you've meant something others?

Comment: @user3467471  Add the output of `dpkg -l | grep freeradius`  too, *after* doing the command advised by Arran.

Comment: yes, it was the right hint by Arran, it was installed from the right place. ie. v 3.0.11 Thank you both!